# How to chain multiple separate JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I know similar questions have been asked before but none of the examples make sense to me. (Any I have found have failed to explain the basics for me with the clarity I need.)

I have four AngularJS functions. Each calls a REST service and does stuff that is unrelated to any of the other functions. E.g.

```
$scope.step1 = function() { $http({  
    method: 'GET',  
    url: "http://www/end/point",  
    cache: true,
    headers: { "Accept": "application/jsonp;odata=verbose" }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.step1data = data;
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
    $scope.logError(data);
});};
```

I  would like to call the four functions in sequence

1. $scope.step1
2. $scope.step2
3. $scope.step3
4. $scope.step4

And catch any errors encountered.

I have narrowed the code to the below but it does not work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$scope.step1().then(function() {
    $scope.step2();
}).then(function() {
    $scope.step3();
}).then(function() {
    $scope.step4();
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your step1, step2, step3 and step4 to return promises like below:

```
    $scope.step1 = function() {
    return $http({  
    method: 'GET',  
    url: "http://www/end/point",  
    cache: true,
    headers: { "Accept": "application/jsonp;odata=verbose" }
   })};

    $scope.step2 = function() {
    return $http({  
    method: 'GET',  
    url: "http://www/end/point",  
    cache: true,
    headers: { "Accept": "application/jsonp;odata=verbose" }
   })};

    $scope.step3 = function() {
    return $http({  
    method: 'GET',  
    url: "http://www/end/point",  
    cache: true,
    headers: { "Accept": "application/jsonp;odata=verbose" }
   })};

    $scope.step4 = function() {
    return $http({  
    method: 'GET',  
    url: "http://www/end/point",  
    cache: true,
    headers: { "Accept": "application/jsonp;odata=verbose" }
   })};
```

Then, chain them together like this:

```
$scope.step1().then(function (step1data) {
  $scope.step1data = step1data;
  $scope.step2().then(function (step2Data) {
    $scope.step2Data = step2Data;
       $scope.step3().then(function (step3Data) {
         $scope.step3Data = step3Data;
         $scope.step4().then(function (step4Data) {
            $scope.step4Data = step4Data;
         });
       });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the promise from each step function to your `then()` callback so that its resulting promise waits for that promise:

```
$scope.step1().then(function() {
    return $scope.step2();
})...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mix asynchronous functions with any kind of logic that JavaScript offers if you execute your code synchronously via [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs). Here is how your code may need to be transformed:

Step 1: Wrap asynchronous function into generic nsynjs-aware wrapper:

```
// generic function to retrieve url
// ctx is a reference to caller pseudo-thread context
var httpUrl = function(ctx,url,$http) {
    var res={};
    $http({  
        method: 'GET',  
        url: url,  
        cache: true,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/jsonp;odata=verbose" }
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        res.data = data;
        ctx.resume() // tells nsynjs to resume caller function
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        ctx.resume(data) // resume caller function with exception
        // or replace with these 2 lines if you don't want exception
        // res.error = data;
        // ctx.resume()
    });
    return res;
};
getUrl.nsynjsHasCallback = true; // this tells nsynjs engine that it
                                // should pause execution and wait until ctx.resume() is called from callback
```

Step 2. Write your logic as if it was synchronous, and put it into function:

```
function synchronousCode(param1, param2) {
    var step1 = function() {
        var data = httpUrl(nsynjsCtx,"nsynjs/examples/data/file1.json").data;
        console.log("data is ready at this point:",data);
        // do staff this data
        return data;
    };
    var step2 = function() {
        var data = httpUrl(nsynjsCtx,"nsynjs/examples/data/file2.json").data;
        console.log("data is ready at this point:",data);
        // do staff this data
        return data;
    };

    console.log( step1(param1) + step2(param2) ); // do more staff with data
}
```

Step 3. Run your synchronous code via nsynjs:

```
nsynjs.run(synchronousCode,{},"value for param1","value for param1",function(){
    console.log("Synchronous Code done");
})
```

More examples here: https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

You need to use promise, in your controller, you should inject $q which will handle promise.

```
 angularApp.controller('YourController', ['$q', '$scope',
    function ($q, $scope) {

        $scope.firstFunction = function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            //Do things you want here...

            console.log(1);

            deferred.resolve();
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        $scope.secondFunction = function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            //Do things you want here...

            console.log(2);

            deferred.resolve();
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        $scope.firstFunction().then(function () {
            $scope.secondFunction.then(function () {
                console.log(3)
            })
        })
    }]);
```

console logs in functions above will print out:

```
1
2
3
```